# creating a device teaming file

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a centos 7 a networking teaming (bonding) using a user input in a python script. C

```
import socket

# IP Address
IPADDR = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print IPADDR
# Netmask
NETMASK = raw_input("Enter Netmask address: ")
PREFIX = sum([bin(int(x)).count("1") for x in NETMASK.split(".")])
print NETMASK
# Gateway
GATEWAY = raw_input("Enter Gateway address: ")
print GATEWAY
# Run command and substitution
os.system("nmcli con add type team con-name team0 ifname team0 config '{"runner":{"name": "activebackup"}}'")
os.system("nmcli con mod team0 ipv4.addresses IPDDR/PREFIX")
os.system("nmcli con mod team0 ipv4.gateway GATEWAY")
os.system("nmcli con mod team0 connection.autoconnect yes")
os.system("nmcli con mod team0 ipv4.method manual")
os.system("nmcli con mod team0 ipv6.method ignore")
```

When I run the script I get this errors:

```
 File "team0.py", line 16
    os.system("nmcli con add type team con-name team0 ifname team0 config '{"runner":{"name": "activebackup"}}'")
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help to find what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Use triple quoting to be able to pass the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is occurring because you are not escaping the quote `"` characters. The interpreter thinks that the string has ended and then trips.

You can use a backslash `\` to escape the quote:

```
os.system("nmcli con add type team con-name team0 ifname team0 config '{\"runner\":{\"name\": \"activebackup\"}}'")
```

In addition, please note that your declared variables are not being picked up when they are declared in string literals. You will need to modify these commands with [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format), for example:

```
os.system("nmcli con mod team0 ipv4.addresses {}/{}".format(IPDDR, PREFIX))
os.system("nmcli con mod team0 ipv4.gateway {}".format(GATEWAY)")
```

See the above documentation and other SO questions for more info about how to use `format`.

Comment: I use both suggestion and the dictionary fail then I sued the back slashes and it work partially.   This is the error: I get   Connection 'team0' (2d656530-cd1f-457c-8ced-05f36390bfbb) successfully added.
Error: failed to modify ipv4.addresses: invalid prefix 'PREFIX'; <1-32> allowed.
Error: failed to modify ipv4.gateway: invalid IP address: Invalid IPv4 address 'GATEWAY'.
Error: Failed to modify connection 'team0': ipv4.addresses: this property cannot be empty for 'method=manual'  The variable "PREFIX" it does not been replace by my variable value

Comment: Thanks a lot guys I was able to fix it with the little help from you all. I totally forgot my variables format. The tips helps. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Sure -- you terminated the string, as shown by the colouring of the text.  It starts at **"nmcli**.  Use a pair of double quotation marks to have them as a literal within the outer string.

```
os.system("nmcli con add type team con-name team0 ifname team0 config '{""runner"":
```

... and so on.  Alternately, put the dictionary value into a variable and append it to the larger string later:

```
my_dict = '{"runner":{"name": "activebackup"}}'
os.system("nmcli con add type team con-name team0 ifname team0 config '"
         + my_dict) + "'"
```

Comment: I think the single-quotes are part of the command, so you'd probably want to change to `"...config '{}'".format(my_dict)`

Comment: Right ... but I'm altering my solution for the direct manipulation, just to illustrate.